# what group does backreference refers to when used with sub() operation?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, python-3.x, regex-group

The following code:

```
>>> text = "imagine a new *world*, a *magic* world"
>>> pattern = re.compile(r'\*(.*?)\*')
>>> pattern.sub(r"<b>\1<\b>", text)
```

outputs:

```
imagine a new <b>world<\x08>, a <\b>magic<\x08> world
```

I have two problems here,

1.) I don't understand why does back reference `'\1'` changes the *magic* part of the text? 
I have read that `'\1'` refers to the first group which is captured.

2.) Why does `<\b>` outputs `<\x08>` even after using `'r'` as prefix. I dosen't happen with `'\n'`.

Comment: @Bakuriu yeah but then it should output:
imagine a new <b>world<\x08>, a <\b>world<\x08> world
as \1 refers to 'world'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went to IRC and people there told me that every time a group is captured with repeated match string, the bacreference is overwritten.

Answer (score 2):

1. [`sub`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) replaces *all* matches, not just the first one. From the documentation:

   > Return the string obtained by replacing the leftmost non-overlapping
   >   occurrences of pattern in string by the replacement repl. [...] The
   >   optional argument `count` is the maximum number of pattern occurrences
   >   to be replaced; count must be a non-negative integer. **If omitted or
   >   zero, all occurrences will be replaced.**
2. `\b` is an escape sequence (for backspace). You should escape it with an other `\`:

   ```
   r'<b>\1<\\b>'
   ```

   Used as:

   ```
   In [4]: pattern.sub(r'<b>\1<\\b>', text)
   Out[4]: 'imagine a new <b>world<\\b>, a <b>magic<\\b> world'
   ```

Escape sequences are interpreted in two different moments:

- By the python compiler, when creating the bytecode, which has to decide which characters to put into the strings.
- By the `re` engine, when performing the substitution.

To understand why double escaping is required you can try to add one backslash at a time:

```
In [18]: print(pattern.sub('<b>\\1<\b>', text))
imagine a new <b>world>, a <b>magic> world

In [19]: print(pattern.sub('<b>\\1<\\b>', text))
imagine a new <b>world>, a <b>magic> world

In [20]: print(pattern.sub('<b>\\1<\\\b>', text))
imagine a new <b>world<>, a <b>magic<> world

In [21]: print(pattern.sub('<b>\\1<\\\\b>', text))
imagine a new <b>world<\b>, a <b>magic<\b> world
```

In `[18]` the `\b` is interpreted by the python compiler, so a real backspace character is put in the string (and, as you can see, when replacing it deletes the previous `<` character)

In `[19]` the `\\` is interpreted as one escaped `\` but, afterwards, the `re` engine sees that you want to replace the some text that contains and escape sequence and reinterprets it, thus yielding the same result as `[18]`.

In `[20]` the `\\` is interpreted as one escaped `\` and the final `\b` as a backspace. The result is that, when replacing, the backspace deletes the `\`.

In `[21]` the four `\\\\` are interpreted as two escape sequences, which the `re` engine interprets as a single `\` followed by a `b` (the expected result).  Using four `\` is equivalent to using raw string literals *plus* one escaping.

Comment: @ColdFusion Shouldn't the replacement be `</b>` not `<\b>`

Comment: @CodeFusion Yes, you must use *both*. Raw string literals + escape. The problem is that escapes are interpreted first by the interpreter when compiling (and the raw string literal is required so that the interpreter doesn't insert a backslash there) and afterwards by the `re` engine.

Comment: @hwnd Probably yes if that's HTML, but the question is not about `/b`, since it doesn't give problems.

Comment: @hwnd, I know that seems obvious but I want to add '<\b>' in the end not to make it bold.

Comment: @Bakuriu, that was very well explained, thanks, but one thing which is still confusing me is '\n' why does it prints normally.